# How can I have Variable Frequency PWM with STM32?

Tags: variables, stm32, frequency, pwm

I am working on an LLC converter project. So I need PWM signals with variable frequency. I mean I need too change frequency real time. For example frequency modulation 40kHZ-80kHZ. Can anyone give me an idea? Which timer mode I have to use ?  Thanks..

Comment: It's totally doable via Timer's prescaler and ARR. The question is, what is your resolution? I mean the steps. Do you need 40kHz-41kHz-42kHz...79kHz-80kHz, or do you need 40kHz- 40.1kHz-40.2kHz-...-79.9kHz-80kHz. Please, specify

Comment: Also, while I'm at it, what is the resolution of duty cycle steps? 0%-50%-100%? 0%-1%-...99%-100%? These are all important questions

Comment: @Ilya Firstly thanks. And I think I will not  change duty cycle ( probably fixed %50). But will use phase shifting (stable a complementary pwm couple and a phase shifting complementary pwm couple). Actually I wanted know that if there was a variable frequency pwm way except setting ARR register. Because before I didnot try to generate variable frequency. So Is it usefull way to dynamically setting ARR?    As for resolution, If I use high clock frequency, seems it will meet my expectation. ( For example 100mHZ timer clock, 0 prescaler, and dynamic ARR value) But I will try I am not sure..

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood from your question and follow-up comments, you want a constant duty cycle (~50%), but you want variable fequency, as well as phase shift. That is totally doable, and you can change the values on the fly, but for the phase shift, I would suggest using two timers. One master, one slave.

Idea:

Master slave controls the phase shift. The period of master slave is equal to the period of the final waveform. It goes from 0 to its ARR, and at some point there is the phase shift value in Compare register, which flips the output of master from LOW to HIGH on its way from 0 to ARR.

The slave is activated by master output change from LOW to HIGH, runs for one period, which is equal to the period of the master (ARR). It outputs PWM to some pin. Once it reaches ARR, it stops (only for master to start it again). Obviously, you need to adjust Compare register for PWM output to keep the duty cycle constant.

I made some crude illustration of what I mean, because discussing timers with text only can be a little (very) tricky. Paint skills 10/10:

[image]

---

How to adjust stuff:

Adjust frequency (period length) by changing ARR of both timers (it's always the same), if you want to keep duty cycle, you will need to immediately adjust compare value to ARR/2 (for ~50% duty cycle) of the slave timer. Make sure the compare value of the phase shifter master is below the ARR if you reduce ARR, otherwise the slave will never get triggered.

Adjust phase shift by changing compare value of the master timer between 0 and ARR.

---

Additional notes:

The master timer is configured to have TRGO (trigger output, master feature) on switch from LOW to HIGH of "compare".

The slave timer is in one pulse mode (OPM), meaning it disables itself after a single period. It will be reactivated by the next master's phase shift pulse (compare HIGH).

The master's signal is supposed to do reset and activation of the timer (resets CNT) (there is a list of modes - what TRGI trigger input does to the slave timer). Resetting the timer will load new values into ARR (see next point).

Both master and slave have ARR buffer enabled. This will allow you to change ARR values, but the changes take effect only when the current cycle ends. This will prevent jitter while changing period length and/or phase shift.

The slave timer is in PWM1 or PWM2 mode, depending on whether you want the first part of the output aveform to be LOW or HIGH, that's all the difference.

---

Helpful example from me:

I have written an implementation of master/slave timers with them activating each other differently purely on registers and with every line of code commented. I was a little new to it all (which shows in the structure of the project), it was literally my first experiment with timers after studying the timers in the reference manual for days, but I tried my best. I have a description of what I do in main.c. You may find it helpful. Note that the timers with the same numbers are similar or even identical across various STM32 devices, so my code is likely portable down to copy-paste into your code (which I'm totally OK with if you or anyone does it). Here is a [link to main.c on my GitHub](https://github.com/ellectroid/STM32F746-CMSIS-Chained-Timers-Demo/blob/main/Src/main.c). I also have oscilloscope screenshots there.

Comment: thanks again. I have tried a smilar way. I made TIM1 master and TIM8 slave. TIM8 is triggering with  "TIM1 channel 2 output compare" (when this channel is high TIM8 begins to pulsing). Actually I achieved phase shift which I want. But I cant change phase dynamically. Because I use TIM1 channel2 as Active Level On Match. So after it turned high , cant turn to low. Thats why I choose a phase for TIM8 at first,  but cant change it. I think this way is usefull but I cant configure it perfectly. Do you have an idea ?

Comment: Try setting slave timer to one pulse mode. Also, what specifically slave mode does TIM8 have?

Comment: TIM1 and TIM8 have complementary pwm and dead time. And I am trying to make an full bridge switching with phase shift. İt works if I choose  constant values for ARR-CRR and constant phase . But when  I try to change them It doesnot work.  I think I have to set more detailed configures. I dont have ossiloscope at home but I set frequency 1sn to see results and tried 0 degree phase and 45 and 180 degrees. It works. But It doesnot work well when I change them on fly

Comment: If you need complementary outputs with dead time, you need only one timer for that. Advanced timers support 2 complementary outputs to 2 pins and with dead time too. And you can use a basic master timer to phase shift this advanced timer just like in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Its a little tricky to answer your question when you dont state the exact hardware you're working with. Seeing your tags i will assume its a member of the the STM32 family.
STM standard timers have registers you usually dont need to interface directly. Hal does that for you. However as far as i am aware Hal does not support such functionalities. The standard STM32 Timer has a TIMx_ARR and a TIMx_CCRn register. These hold some of the configuration necessary for PWM generation. You should be able to change your frequency by adjusting the ARR register and the Duty-Cycle by adjusting the CCRn register.

Be carful with that approach tho as it usually has no inbuilt protection. You will not damage your device but it is very easy to produce unintended behavior.
You also need to consider the prescaler values and the general configuration of your timer.

For detailed information refer to the Chapter: GPTIM in the reference Manual of your device as i can not give you a more detailed description with the little information you have provided.